# Restore hard disk to factory conditions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, restore, default

I am a Ubuntu newbie. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from bootable USB.
Unfortunately, before using the USB key, I tried to boot and install Ubuntu from a hard disk.

Now, I cannot use this hard disk anymore. I restored easily my USB following these steps: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/. But I know that for hard disk the process is more complicated.

Is there documentation online that could help me restore my hard disk back to normal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using gparted, a gui tool that you can install into a live usb session. fdisk/gdisk are command line tools that will do the job as well, gparted is just much more user friendly.

Just boot into a live usb session, open a terminal and run 'sudo apt-get install gparted -y', and once it finishes go to your programs and run gparted on your hard drive.

This will also detect your usb disk, but you should be able to tell which one is your usb disk by the size it says it is.

Answer (score 2):

Look for instructions on using `fdisk` (with care!  It's easy to erase the wrong device!), or use the GUI tools (`gparted` or `disks` or KDE Partition Manager, depending on the GUI you use -- and still be careful that you're clearing the right device).  All you need to make the hard disk a blank one again is to create a new partition table, though you could optionally partition and format one or more volumes on the drive.